# Export data into multiple worksheet in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2

i am working on MVC application i have to export my table data and i am using following code :

```
     public ActionResult ExportData()
    {
        GridView gv = new GridView();
        gv.DataSource = db.Studentrecord.ToList();
        gv.DataBind();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Marklist.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        Response.Charset = "";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        gv.RenderControl(htw);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();

        return RedirectToAction("StudentDetails");
    }
```

this creates single worksheet i want another worksheet where i will have other table data.Please help how to export data in multiple worksheet ?

Comment: you aren't creating any worksheets there, you're using excel to open an html page with a table in it.

Comment: this defaultly create one Worksheet , how do i create new one and specify data to export in it ?

Comment: +1 @BlackICE. It's incredible how many people are failing to understand what the Excel format is.

Comment: @DharaPPatel, you will have to use a (third-party) library to create a real Excel file because worksheets are only supported in Excel files. Right now you don't have an excel file. Just an HTML and you happened to open it with Excel.

Comment: is there any option to do that with this code?

Comment: No, there isn't such option.

Answer (score 2):

How about using a 3rd party library instead? This is free: https://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/

```
string file = "C:\\newdoc.xls";
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
Worksheet worksheet = new Worksheet("First Sheet");
Worksheet worksheet2 = new Worksheet("Second Sheet");
workbook.Worksheets.Add(worksheet);
workbook.Worksheets.Add(worksheet2);
workbook.Save(file);
```

This provides a much more fluid user experience as you are actually creating a real Excel file, not just a HTML file which Excel happens to read.

Comment: How do i write my tabular data in separate worksheet ? this should ask user to save file in file system

Comment: Literally the first page of the link I posted demonstrates how to output data in a tabular format. Use `worksheet.Cells[X, Y]` to insert data the same way as you would in Excel